# Sum up specific rows for each column

Tags: r, sum, rowsum

I'm sure my problem is easy to solve unfortunately I can't come up with a simple solution for my self. I want to sum up certain rows of a dataset for each column.

My dataset looks like this:

```
    GIVN  MICP  GFIP
-2  0.01  0.02  0.01
-1  0.03 -0.01  0.01
0  -0.02 -0.03  0.01
1  -0.04  0.05 -0.02
2   0.01  0.02  0.03
```

Now I want it to be summed once from row -1 to 1 and from row -2 to 1 for each column.

This should look like this for -1 to 1:

```
    GIVN  MICP  GFIP
   -0.03  0.01  0.00
```

With the function colSums I only add all rows from each column, which is not what I want to do.

Comment: You might want to think about using `colSums` with a subset of your data (e.g. data[2:4,] for the second, third and fourth rows of your data)

Comment: `colSums(df[which(rownames(df) == -1):which(rownames(df) == 1),])`

Comment: @p0bs thank you, exactly what I needed

Comment: @M.Berns Pleased to hear it!

Comment: @Sotos even better many thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is an option with `dplyr`, but it's a little clunky. The trickiness comes from the fact that you're not cleanly cutting the ID into mutually-exclusive groups, so you need to operate with essentially separate data frames, then bind them back together.

First you need your rownames to be numeric, so you can compare number ranges.

You'll filter the data for the groups of IDs; `dplyr::between` is a utility function for finding whether a number is in a range, inclusive of the range's endpoints. I'm adding a variable with `mutate` to specify which group data comes from; if you don't need that spelled out, you can drop the `mutate`s and just add a `.id` argument in `bind_rows`. You just will need some way of differentiating the groups for when you summarize.

This goes inside a `bind_rows` call, which is like `rbind` but can take more than 2 data frames at once. Then `group_by` and summarize. If you have too many columns and naming them in `summarise_at` becomes cumbersome, you could instead drop the ID and use `summarise_all` or `summarise_if`.

```r
library(dplyr)
df$id <- as.numeric(row.names(df))

bind_rows(
  df %>% filter(between(id, -1, 1)) %>% mutate(group = "-1 to 1"),
  df %>% filter(between(id, -2, 1)) %>% mutate(group = "-2 to 1")
) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(GIVN:GFIP), sum)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 4
#>   group    GIVN  MICP  GFIP
#>   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 -1 to 1 -0.03  0.01  0   
#> 2 -2 to 1 -0.02  0.03  0.01
```

<sup>Created on 2018-12-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>